# javascript real time search box

Tags: javascript

I have my search box almost finished, I think the logic of the code is correct, but it is throwing me an error on the line that I want to add the "hide" class, if someone would be so kind as to give me a hand I would appreciate it.

Error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'classList') at prueba.js:301:19 at Array.forEach (<anonymous>) at HTMLInputElement.<anonymous> (prueba.js:296:13)
```

Code:

```js
const traigoJson = async()=> {
  const respuesta = await fetch ('../stock.json')
  const data = await respuesta.json()

  let contenedor = document.getElementById("container")

  data.forEach((producto, indice) => {

  let card = document.createElement("div")

  card.classList.add("col-xl-3", "col-lg-3", "col-md-6", "col-sm-6", "hide", `${producto.deporte}`, "products")
  card.innerHTML = `<div class="glasses_box">
      <figure><img src="${producto.imagen}" alt="esta es una foto de ${producto.nombre}"/></figure>
      <h3><span class="blu">$</span>${producto.precio}</h3>
      <p class="product-name">${producto.nombre}</p>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary boton-comprar" id="asd" onClick = "agregarAlCarrito (${indice})">COMPRAR</button>
   </div>`
  contenedor.appendChild(card)
  
  producto.card = card;
})
}

traigoJson()


const searchInput = document.getElementById("search-input")
const card = document.querySelectorAll(".products")
searchInput.addEventListener("input", e => {
  const value = e.target.value.toLowerCase()

  productos.forEach(producto => {
    const isVisible =
      producto.nombre.toLowerCase().includes(value) ||
      producto.deporte.toLowerCase().includes(value)

    producto.card.classList.toggle("hide", !isVisible)
  
  })
})
```

Comment: Can you also include the exact error in your post?

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'classList')
    at prueba.js:301:19
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at HTMLInputElement.<anonymous> (prueba.js:296:13)

Comment: Sounds like `producto.card` is undefined!

Comment: If you search `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined` on SO, I imagine that you'll probably find more than a couple of questions asking the same thing. It usually comes down to debugging and making sure that properties are what you think they are.

Comment: yeah, but maybe my logic is incorrect, there is probablly another or better way to make the instant search

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You create a card element for each product, but then do not add the card to the product item.  And so the code errors during the search when trying to get the value of `producto.card`.

In the code below I've added this line to the `forEach` loop:

```
producto.card = card;
```

This change should be enough to get you started.

```js
let productos = [{
    nombre: "1",
    deporte: "d",
    precio: "100",
    imagen: "https://via.placeholder.com/100"
  },
  {
    nombre: "2",
    deporte: "d",
    precio: "100",
    imagen: "https://via.placeholder.com/100"
  },
  {
    nombre: "3",
    deporte: "d",
    precio: "100",
    imagen: "https://via.placeholder.com/100"
  },
  {
    nombre: "4",
    deporte: "d",
    precio: "100",
    imagen: "https://via.placeholder.com/100"
  },
  {
    nombre: "5",
    deporte: "d",
    precio: "100",
    imagen: "https://via.placeholder.com/100"
  }
];



const crearCards = () => {

  let contenedor = document.getElementById("container")

  productos.forEach((producto, indice) => {

    let card = document.createElement("div")

    card.classList.add("col-xl-3", "col-lg-3", "col-md-6", "col-sm-6", "hide", `${producto.deporte}`, "products")

    card.innerHTML = `<div class="glasses_box">
        <figure><img src="${producto.imagen}" alt="esta es una foto de ${producto.nombre}"/></figure>
        <h3><span class="blu">$</span>${producto.precio}</h3>
        <p class="product-name">${producto.nombre}</p>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary boton-comprar" id="asd" onClick = "agregarAlCarrito (${indice})">COMPRAR</button>
     </div>`

    contenedor.appendChild(card)
    
    producto.card = card;

  })
}


const searchInput = document.getElementById("search-input")
const card = document.querySelectorAll(".products")

searchInput.addEventListener("input", e => {

  const value = e.target.value.toLowerCase()
  
  productos.forEach(producto => {
    const isVisible =
      producto.nombre.toLowerCase().includes(value) ||
      producto.deporte.toLowerCase().includes(value)

    producto.card.classList.toggle("hide", !isVisible)

  })
})

crearCards();
```

```css
.hide {
   display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="container" class="container">
  Type 1, 2, 3, 4, or 5 into the search box to test:
  <input id="search-input" class="form-control my-2" placeholder="search">
  <div class="products"></div>
</div>

<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: @pipe - I updated the snippet to make your search box show matching items.

Comment: hi, now im ussing async function to create my cards, and the searchbox is not working.... im adding the new code to the initial question

Comment: im new in this .json and async features, and now my code is completely broken.